# Connecting to MQ channel using Java client :CERTLABL error

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq

I'm working on a microservice in Java to connect to an IBM Websphere MQ V8.0 through SSL. However, I am seeing this error in the logs:

> JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2059' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE')

At the MQ end the error is `CSQX673E` and the reason is:

> The SSL or TLS channel's channel-name is configured to use certificate label: cert-label. However, the remote peer did not send the necessary information to allow the local channel to use the correct certificate. The remote host is conn-id.

Can somebody please let me know how to pass this parameter, using Java.

As per my understanding, `CERTLABL` is not a part of the certificate.

Comment: This is not possible, the IBM MQ Classes for Java and IBM MQ Classes for JMS do not support the SNI feature of TLS that allows them to send the channel name over during the TLS negotiation.  You would need to connect to a channel on the queue manager that uses the queue mangers default certificate.

Comment: Thanks. Even Java 8 or Java 9 wont support this. MQ client classes for MQ version 8.0 is written in Java 7? Also believe Java 8 supports SNI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Note the information below is documented the same in MQ v8.0.0, v9.0.0, and v9.1.0 knowledge centers.

---

IBM Documents that in the
IBM MQ 8.0.0 Knowledge center page [IBM MQ>Security>Security overview>IBM MQ security mechanisms>Security protocols in IBM MQ>The SSL or TLS key repository>Digital certificate labels, understanding the requirements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014340_.htm) the following:

> IBM MQ Version 8.0 supports the use of multiple certificates on the
>   same queue manager, using a per-channel certificate label attribute.
>   Inbound channels to the queue manager (for example, server connection
>   or receiver) rely on detecting the channel name using TLS Server Name
>   Indication (SNI), in order to present the correct certificate from the
>   queue manager.

The same page also documents this:

> Note that inbound channels (including receiver, cluster-receiver,
>   unqualified server, and server-connection channels) only send the
>   configured certificate if the IBM MQ version of the remote peer fully
>   supports certificate label configuration, and the channel is using a
>   TLS CipherSpec.
>
> In all other cases, the queue manager CERTLABL parameter determines
>   the certificate sent. In particular, the following only ever receive
>   the certificate configured by the CERTLABL parameter of the queue
>   manager, regardless of the channel-specific label setting:
>
> - All current Java and JMS clients.
> - Versions of IBM MQ prior to Version 8.0.

---

IBM also documents the similar information in the IBM MQ 8.0.0 Knowledge center page [IBM MQ>Reference>Configuration reference>Channel attributes>Channel attributes in alphabetical order>Certificate label (CERTLABL)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q113280_.htm):

> Inbound channels (including RCVR, CLUSRCVR, unqualified SERVER, and
>   SVRCONN channels) will only send the configured certificate if the
>   IBM® MQ version of the remote peer fully supports certificate label
>   configuration and the channel is using a TLS CipherSpec. If that is
>   not the case, the queue manager CERTLABL attribute determines the
>   certificate sent. This restriction is because the certificate label
>   selection mechanism for inbound channels depends upon a TLS protocol
>   extension that is not supported in all cases. **In particular, *Java™
>   clients, JMS clients*, and all versions of IBM MQ prior to Version 8.0
>   do not support the required protocol extension and will only ever
>   receive the certificate configured by the queue manager CERTLABL
>   attribute, regardless of the channel-specific label setting.**

---

As you stated Java 8 does support SNI, but apparently IBM has not yet implemented the feature in the IBM MQ Classes for Java or IBM MQ Classes for JMS.

One possible solution I can think of is that you could figure out which underlying function MQ calls to create the TLS session and override this to set the SNI attribute to a value that MQ will recognize on the queue manger with code like the following:

```
SSLParameters params = sslSocket.getSSLParameters();
params.setServerNames(serverNames);
sslSocket.setSSLParameters(params);
```

---

IBM has documented the format that the channel name is passed in the SNI in the Technote "[IBM WebSphere MQ: How does MQ provide multiple certificates (CERTLABL) capability](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21978780)":

> The SNI address used by MQ is based upon the channel name that is
>   being requested, followed by a suffix of ".chl.mq.ibm.com".
>
> MQ channel names are mapped to be valid SNI names as follows:
>
> - Upper case letters A-Z are folded to lower case
> - Digits 0 through 9 are left unchanged
> - All other characters including lower-case letters a-z are converted into their 2-digit hexadecimal ASCII character code followed by a
>     hyphen.
> - lower case letters a through z map to "61-" through "7a-" respectively
> - percent (%) maps to "25-"
> - hyphen (-) maps to "2d-"
> - dot (.) maps to "2e-"
> - forward slash (/) maps to "2f-"
> - underscore (_) maps to "5f-"
>
> On EBCDIC platforms, the channel name is converted to ASCII before
>   this mapping is applied. As an example, channel name "TO.QMGR1" maps
>   to an SNI address of "to2e-qmgr1.chl.mq.ibm.com".
>
> By contrast, the lower case channel name "to.qmgr1" maps onto SNI
>   address of "74-6f-2e-71-6d-67-72-1.chl.mq.ibm.com".

Comment: Hi Josh, Can you please provide some evidence to support this statement " IBM has not yet implemented the feature in the IBM MQ Classes for Java or IBM MQ Classes for JMS". That would really helpful for me to reach a conclusion

Comment: @djhi89 directly above my statement is a quote from the IBM MQ document where I have bolded a statement that directly says Java™ clients, JMS clients do not support the required protocol extension to receive the channel-specific cert.

Comment: @djhi89 you have also observed the behavior first hand as described in your question.

Comment: @JoshMc I have same problem and I don't understand this answer at all. At MQ side I have two private certificates in keystore and clients have public parts of those in their truststore. With CERTLBL on qm everything works with both certificates. But the moment when I override qm CERTLBL with a CERTLBL atribute on channel no client can connect with error AMQ9673: The channel 'XXX' did not send the correct certificate to the remote peer.

This error makes no sense as documentation states channel CERTLBL is used to override qm CERTLBL attribute. Optional auth, MQ 9.0.5.0, AIX

Comment: @Talijanac are the clients Java based?

Comment: My answer is specific to Java/JMS API clients.  They do not provide SNI, so cert label feature does not work with them at v8.0/9.0 LTS/9.0 CD/9.1 LTS.  The docs for IBM MQ 9.1 CD have old references but from what I can tell it looks like IBM added SNI to Java and JMS API clients at 9.1.1 CD release and it is included in 9.2.  I'm sending feed back to IBM on the KC pages that seem to be out of date.

Comment: @JoshMC Thanks on response. I think I figure it out. When CERTLABL is used on receiving channel it always leads to AMQ9673 error. It doesn't matter if certificates are valid or not. This features is NOT "alternative" server certificate for MQ. My desire was to issue new server self-signed certificate, but without forcing clients to immediately upgrade their trustores with new certificate. Instead I wanted to provide them with alternative channel to which they can upgrade at a time when they are ready.

Comment: Counter-intuitively CERTLABL is a feature of invoking channel. You should set-up CERTLABL on invoking channel which then "asks" MQ server for certificate override to a desired certificate. As such this feature is usable only in MQ-MQ communication.

Comment: I experimented with Java clients, standalone apps and WebSphere AS. But I also need this to work on .NET and C clients.

Comment: @Talijanac It works on both clients and servers, connecting channels and receiving channels.   But java based clients do not support it until 9.1.1 or 9.2.0.0.  What you describe should work if the client supports it. .net and c clients should support it.